# Angular UI-Router : Only able to access the Web App with Index.html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am creating a Angualr 1.5 app using Ui-Router module for routing. But by default, my application wont open when I run the localhost:xxxx, instead I need to browse till Index.html like http://localhost:xxxx/src/client/index.html

My routing config is below. I am not able to identify the root cause for not able to access without index.html. Any help is really great.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
            $stateProvider.state("home", {
                url: "/home",

                views: {
                    // parent view.
                    "": {
                        template: "<home-component></home-component>"
                    },

                    // Home page split into 3 parts - Buy section/popular/promotions for better modularity.
                    "buy@home": {
                        template: "<buy-component></buy-component>"
                    },
                    "popular@home": {
                        template: "<popular-component></popular-component>"
                    },
                    "promotions@home": {
                        template: "<promotion-component></promotion-component>"
                    }
                }
            })
           .state("login", {
               url: "/login",
               template: "<login-component on-navigate='model.isNavbarActive = isNavbarActive'></login-component>"
           })
            .state("register", {
                url: "/register/",
                template: "<registration-component on-navigate='model.isNavbarActive = isNavbarActive'></registration-component>",
                params: {
                    userExist: {
                        value: "",
                        squash: true
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: You saying you can't see the difference between `/` and `/src/client/index.html`? Looks like you simply need to set your HTTP server's document root to the appropriate location, probably `src/client`

Comment: Phil, is that it supposed to work by updating server root? I am using IIS and it has few other non-SPA apps as well.